# combine and align ggplot, including one square with control of their height

Tags: r, ggplot2, egg, cowplot, patchwork

I'm trying to vertically align several `ggplots`, including **one that must be square** (using coord_fixed or any other means). I also want to be able to **control the relative heights** of the different plots. The desired plot look would like this, the number of rectangular: ([wanted plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oEew.png)). The number of rectangular plots beneath the square one can vary from 1 to 5.

I've read other SO threads, including this one ([Vertically align of plots of different heights using cowplot::plot_grid() when using coord_equal()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924219/vertically-align-of-plots-of-different-heights-using-cowplotplot-grid-when-u)).

So far: I can align plots, including with one that is square (with `egg` or `patchwork`) but I don't manage to adjust the relaive heights of the panels.
Below is what I tried (using `cowplot`, `egg` or `patchwork` packages).

**Using coord_fixed**

```
#data
a = data.frame(x = seq(0,10), y = seq(10,20), z = runif(11))
b = data.frame(x = seq(0,10), y = runif(11))

#generate ggplot
library(ggplot2)
p1 = ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + coord_fixed()
p2 = ggplot(b, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()


#align with cowplot => alignment not working if p1 is squared.
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1,p2,p2, ncol = 1, align = 'v', axis = 'lr')

#align with patchwork => working with p1 squared, but can't control the relative heights
library(patchwork)
p1 + p2 + p2 + plot_layout(nrow = 3)              #aligned, p1 being square
p1 + p2 + p2 + plot_layout(nrow = 3, 
                           heights = c(3, 1, 1))  #not aligned

#same, it does not seem to work with egg.
library(egg)
egg::ggarrange(p1, p2, p2, ncol = 1) 
egg::ggarrange(p1, p2, p2, ncol = 1, heights = c(3,1,1))
```

--

**A alternative strategy** would be to not use coord_fixed for p1, **play with the export file dimensions** and export at the "right" dimensions

```
p1bis = ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + geom_raster()
plot_grid(p1bis,p2,p2, ncol = 1, align = 'v', axis = 'lr', rel_heights = c(4,1,1))
ggsave("temp.pdf", width = 18, height = 24.5, units = "cm")
```

But I'm not clear on how to calculate the width:height ratio of the export PDF document in a dynamic manner. Is there a way to extract (in npc units?) the width and height of the panel.border?

--

I also came across the `ggh4x` package, which, like egg, contains a function to set the panel size. But the panelsize information seems to be lost when combining with patchwork

```
library(ggh4x)
p1f = p1bis + force_panelsizes(rows = unit(10, "cm"), cols = unit(10, "cm"))
p2f = p2    + force_panelsizes(cols = unit(10, "cm"), rows = unit(3, "cm"))
p1f + p2f + p2f + plot_layout(nrow = 3)
```

Do you have any other ideas? Am I missing something trivial somewhere?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

The case of fixed aspects plots is described on the {patchwork} [website](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#fixed-aspect-plots-1):

> A special case when it comes to assembling plots are when dealing with
> fixed aspect plots, such as those created with coord_fixed(),
> coord_polar(), and coord_sf(). It is not possible to simultaneously
> assign even dimensions and align fixed aspect plots.
>
> ...
>
> Which solution is needed is probably dependent on the specific use case.

In your case one way to do it, would be to nest the plots:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p22 <- p2 + p2 + plot_layout(nrow = 2)      
p1 + p22 + plot_layout(nrow = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This gives no fine tuned control over the heights, but we could adjust the nested plots using `plot_spacer()`s:

```r
library(patchwork)

p22 <- plot_spacer() + p2 + plot_spacer() + p2 + plot_spacer() + plot_layout(heights = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1))      

p1 + p22 + plot_layout(nrow = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes, nesting plot is a strategy that I considered. The addition of spacer is a good idea too. But, as you said, it is a way-around that does not offer a full control of the relative heights. Ideally I'd like to limit post-editing using Inkscape. We'll see if someone come-up with alternative ideas.