# ggplot: Horizontally align of plots of different widths with fixed coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

Building on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924219/vertically-align-of-plots-of-different-heights-using-cowplotplot-grid-when-u), I am trying to do the exact same, but horizontally instead of vertically.

The solution accepted in the question doesn't seem to work when the alignment is vertical.

Can anyone explain why? And how to fix it?

Here's an example unsing `egg`, as suggested in the answer to the original question.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(y = rep(1:10, 2), x = 1:20)
dat2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
plot1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_equal()
plot2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_equal()
egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, nrow = 1)
```

Output: [image]

Notice that the plot on the left lost its coord_equal in favour of the two plots having the same width.

Comment: Could you not specify the width of the plots, e.g. `egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, nrow = 1, widths = c(2, 1))`?  Even make it reflect the data, e.g. `egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, nrow = 1, widths = c(max(dat1$x),max(dat2$x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `patchwork` package.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

dat1 <- data.frame(y = rep(1:10, 2), x = 1:20)
dat2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
plot1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_equal()
plot2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_equal()
```

Use `+` to put plots side-by-side.

```r
plot1 + plot2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: So elegant, thank you. Still puzzled by the different behaviour of the vertical and horizontal alignments.