# How to choose values for plot.margin to add more space in the top right of plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

With sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-10-1", "2021-10-2", "2021-10-3", 
"2021-10-4", "2021-10-5", "2021-10-6", "2021-10-7", "2021-10-8", 
"2021-10-9", "2021-10-10", "2021-10-11", "2021-10-12", "2021-10-13", 
"2021-10-14"), value = c(190.3, 174.9, 163.2, 168.4, 168.6, 168.2, 
163.5, 161.6, 172.9, 166.5, 175.2, 197.7, 212.1, 177.9), type = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

and code to plot below:

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x=date, y=value, group=type, color = type, fill = type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.4, position = "identity") +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=20),
    # plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 1.5, 1.2),"cm")
    # top, right, bottom, left
    # plot.margin=unit(c(0, 1.2, 1.5, 10), "pt")
    plot.margin=unit(rep(1, 4),'lines')
        ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = range(df$value)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = range(df$date)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(min(df$value), max(df$value)), linetype='solid', col=colors[1]) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(date %in% max(date), as.character(date), ""), y = max(value)), color = colors[3], vjust=-0.2, hjust=1, size=6)
```

Out:

[image]

As you can see, the date in red box is not inside of plot, I've
tried to adjust margin by adding `plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 1.5, 1.2), "cm")`; `plot.margin=unit(c(0, 1.2, 1.5, 10), "pt")`, `plot.margin=unit(rep(1, 4),'lines')`, etc., (even negative values) to `theme()`, but I didn't success.

I know four values in `unit` represent `top, right, bottom, left`, but I don't find a way to correctly adjust them.

Someone could help? Sincere thanks at advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `expand` parameter to the scale function. This parameters takes an "expansion vector" which is used to add some space between the data and the axes.

By replicating your code, I was able to visualize the date (within the margin) by adding `expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1), add = c(1, 0))` to `scale_y_continuous()`.

Note that I am also using the `expansion()` function to create the expansion vector which will only expand the top y axis allowing us to visualize the date completely.

So the code would be:

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x=date, y=value, group=type, color = type, fill = type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.4, position = "identity") +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=20),
    # plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 1.5, 1.2),"cm")
    # top, right, bottom, left
    # plot.margin=unit(c(0, 1.2, 1.5, 10), "pt")
    plot.margin=unit(rep(1, 4),'lines')
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = range(df$value),
                 expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1), add = c(1, 0))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = range(df$date)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(min(df$value), max(df$value)), linetype='solid', col="grey40") +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(date %in% max(date), as.character(date), ""), y = max(value)), color = "grey50", vjust=-0.2, hjust=1, size=6)
```

Out:

[image]

Here are some more information on this parameter and `expansion()`:

- [How does ggplot scale_continuous expand argument work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170871/10740287)
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.5/topics/expansion

Comment: Thanks a lot, if I need to add more space for left-bottom?

Comment: I find `plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 1.5, 1.2),"cm")` and `expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1), add = c(1, 0))` simultaneously solve the problem. Thanks.