# How to increase the default y-axis limit in ggplot when scales in facet_wrap() are set to "free"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to figure out how to change the global default setting of the y-axis limit in ggplot when `facet_wrap()` is used and scales are "free". I have searched the site but couldn't find any solution to my problem. I know I could build each plot separately and then assemble them using `cowplot::plot_grid()` or something similar but this will be cumbersome with 10 subplots.

**Example data and plot:**

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble(
  var = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 4)),
  id = c(rep(1:4, 2)),
  mean = c(23, 24, 21, 22, 154, 153, 152, 151),
  sd = c(rep(c(2, 10), each = 4)),
  diff = c(rep(letters[1:4], 2))
)

ggplot(d, aes(id, mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd,
                    ymax = mean + sd)) +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = id,
    y = mean + sd,
    vjust = -2,
    label = diff
  )) +
  facet_wrap( ~ var, scales = "free_y")
```

**Resulting graph:**
[image]

The problem I am encountering is that the letters are out of range when using the `vjust = -2` argument. I am aware that in this example I can simply change the `vjust` argument but in my actual dataset this won't resolve the issue unfortunately. So my question is, assuming `vjust = -2` is fixed, is there a way to increase the default y-axis limits when `scales = "free"` in `facet_wrap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to expand the axis limits.

```r
ggplot(d, aes(id, mean)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd,
                      ymax = mean + sd)) +
    geom_text(aes(
        x = id,
        y = mean + sd,
        vjust = -2,
        label = diff
    )) +
    facet_wrap( ~ var, scales = "free_y") + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.2)))
```

[image]

This increases the top range by 20% and the bottom by 10%. AFAIK, the [defaults are `mult = c(0.05, 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170871/how-does-ggplot-scale-continuous-expand-argument-work).